# Confirming whether a user is registered, using Optional class in Java 8

Tags: java, optional

I start to learn Java 8 and I wondering is that kind of using Optional class is correct?

```
@Override
public Response confirmRegister(Request request) {
    return mailTokenRepository.findByToken(request.getToken()).map(mailToken -> {
        if (mailToken.getTypeToken().equals(TypeToken.REGISTER)
                && mailToken.getToken().equals(request.getToken())) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findOne(mailToken.getUser().getId())).map(user -> {
                user.setBlock(false);
                userRepository.save(user);
                mailTokenRepository.delete(mailToken);
                return jsonService.prepareResponseForUser(StatusMessage.SUCCESS, "SUCCESS_REGISTERED", null, null,
                        true);
            }).orElseGet(() -> jsonService.prepareErrorResponse("INCORRECT_DATA"));
        } else
            return jsonService.prepareErrorResponse("INCORRECT_DATA");
    }).orElseGet(() -> jsonService.prepareErrorResponse("INCORRECT_DATA"));

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning your question about the usage of `Optional`: yes, this usage *is* correct and it roughly respects the principles of functional programming.

However, I would recommend a few changes to increase the readability of this piece of code:

1) `jsonService.prepareErrorResponse("INCORRECT_DATA")` appears three times: it needs to be extracted into a dedicated method.

2) The main valid return case starting with `return Optional.ofNullable` should also be extracted into a dedicated method.

3) The condition should also be extracted.

After this refactoring, the code will resemble something like

```
public Response confirmRegister2(Request request) {
  return mailTokenRepository.findByToken(request.getToken())
                            .map(mailToken -> {
    if (isTokenValid(mailToken, request)) {
      return responseForUser(mailToken).orElseGet(this::errorResponse);
    } else {
      return this.errorResponse();
    }
  }).orElseGet(this::errorResponse);
}

private boolean isTokenValid(MailToken mailToken, Request request) {
  return mailToken.getTypeToken().equals(TypeToken.REGISTER)
         && mailToken.getToken().equals(request.getToken());
}

private Response errorResponse() {
  return jsonService.prepareErrorResponse("INCORRECT_DATA");
}

private Optional<Response> responseForUser(MailToken mailToken) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findOne(mailToken.getUser().getId()))
                .map(user -> {
                      user.setBlock(false);
                      userRepository.save(user);
                      mailTokenRepository.delete(mailToken);
                      return jsonService.prepareResponseForUser(StatusMessage.SUCCESS,
                                                              "SUCCESS_REGISTERED", null, null, true);
                    });
}
```

... which is definitely more readable and easier to understand. :)

Comment: What do you think about replace function isTokenValid by BiPredicate<MailToken, Request> and function errorResponse by Function<String, Response> (I want to pass response message by parameter)?

Comment: @Mateusz, I think that such replacements are possible if you want a more generic method. But be careful, avoid over-engineering and complexity, keep it testable... Can you give an example of how you would like to introduce these replacements?

Comment: private BiPredicate<MailToken, Request> isTokenValid = (mailToken, request) -> mailToken.getTypeToken().equals(TypeToken.REGISTER) && mailToken.getToken().equals(request.getToken());


private Function<String, Response> errorResponse = x -> jsonService.prepareErrorResponse(x);

Comment: @Mateusz, -> _I updated original post_ -> I'd not recommend to reformulate the methods this way, this increases the complexity and does not bring any real improvements. I thought your initial idea was to change the method signature and pass the functions as arguments: `public Response confirmRegister2(Request request, BiPredicate<MT, R> tokenValidityCheck, Supplier<Response> errorResponseSupplier)`.

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion to the code provided is very clear: why...

The problem goes very deep and has its roots in the JAVA programming language. While other language benefit from expressiveness you have to be very careful in using these new language features to NOT loose expressiveness in JAVA.

My first impression was that the code is lumpy. You have to understand it in the whole to make little changes and get the structural dependencies clear.

My second thought came during disassembling the responsibilities. This code is resistent against refactoring.

After I finished my refactoring I came up with following issues:

1. You looked up the mailToken by request.getToken() from your repository and compare it afterwards against the request.getToken() again. Don't you trust your repository to give you back what you requested? I allowed myself to delete this fragment...
2. You have several abstraction levels within one method. In my refactoring I extracted several methods so each method contains statements of one level of abstraction.
3. The usage of Optional may be correct but inappropriate. I ommited it completely
4. You have two ways to exit your confirmRegister-method. Normal and Exceptional. I reformulated it to express these situations clearly. A normal control flow and different exceptional control flows that ALL converge to a single exceptional exit with the possibility to differentiate it if you want. So you haven't these several response-build-statements that all do the same.
5. the multiple return-statements made it hard to extract methods. I avoided multiple returns all the time to keep my code refactoring-friendly.

So the entry method looks like this:

```
public Response confirmRegister(Request request) {

    Response response = null;

    MailToken mailToken = mailTokenRepository.findByToken(request.getToken());

    try {

        checkMailToken(mailToken));
        unlockUser(mailToken.getUser());

        response = buildResponseForUser();

    } catch (ConfirmationException e)
        response = buildErrorResponse(e);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Now all helper methods:

```
private Response buildResponseForUser() {
    return jsonService.prepareResponseForUser(StatusMessage.SUCCESS, "SUCCESS_REGISTERED", null, null, true);
}


private Response buildErrorResponse(ConfirmationException e) {
    // evaluation of exception to allow different error responses
    return jsonService.prepareErrorResponse("INCORRECT_DATA");
}


private void unlockUser(User user) {

    User user = userRepository.findOne(user.getId());

    if (user != null) {
        user.setBlock(false);
        userRepository.save(user);
        mailTokenRepository.delete(mailToken);
    } else {
        throw new ConfirmationException("unknown user");
    }

}


private void checkMailToken(MailToken mailToken) {

    if (mailToken == null) {
        throw new ConfirmationException("unknown token");
    } 

    boolean isRegisterToken = mailToken.getTypeToken().equals(TypeToken.REGISTER);

    if (!isRegisterToken) {
        throw new ConfirmationException("token is not a register token");
    }

}
```

Finally the usecase-specific exception:

```
private static class ConfirmationException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5298407767720081710L;

    public ConfirmationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: I dislike that you're using Exceptions as a control-flow tool here, but this is a vast improvement over the previous bit of code ... Sidenote: if you expect the exception to be handled by the caller, it makes little sense to have it inherit `RuntimeException`.

Comment: I do not use exceptions as a control-flow "tool". If you look at each method that throws an exception: Each method defines a normal control flow and an exceptional control flow. I am not throwing any exception because I WANT to catch it at a special location. I throw exceptions if the normal control flow cannot be finished in the semantic context of the method. And the reason why I am catching it there where I catch it: It is a technology border. Further code will not be able to handle these exceptions properly because further code will communicate only "Responses".

Comment: And you are right: I could have used checked exceptions.

Comment: You're using exceptions as control flow... instead of `if (checkMailToken(mailToken)) {` which would be normal control flow you're expecting checkMailToken to throw an exception, invalidating the control flow assumption. That's what I dislike...

Comment: You are encoding the exceptional case in true/false. Why using exceptions anyway? Technically you are right. But my argument is on the semantic level. The point is that there is no reason to proceed to unlock the user if the mail token is stale in ANY case. It's an all or nothing situation. I would agree if you have another possibility to reach unlock the user EVEN if the mail token is invalid. This would be considered as a "normal control flow". But the WHOLE process is ALL about the mail token which makes "the control flow" exceptional if the token is invalid.